# override close action in eclipse editor

Tags: java, editor, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a eclipse rcp application in which i had created a editor which extends EditorPart.

I want to do some release resource work in its `close()` editor action, so i want to override its close action or any method that just came in to action before to close event.

I had tried `dispose()` but it to late to work on it.

Or is there any specific listener that listen close event.

i want to have like that:

```
@override
public void close()
{
  //do something resource release related task.
}
```

**Update:** basically i want to intercept close event for a editor.

Comment: Why is `dispose` too late?

Comment: @Greg-449 At point of dispose we can not have reference of that editor that seems to have close event.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `IPartListener` for this purpose:

```
public class YourEditor extends EditorPart {

@Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(new IPartListener() {

            @Override
            public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void partDeactivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void partBroughtToTop(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override disposeListener().

```
parent.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {

    @Override
    public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
        releaseAllResource();

    }
});
```